# Wordpress w3tc plugin and fragment caching issue

Tags: wordpress, caching, fragment, w3-total-cache

I apologize for my English, I hope you will understand me.
So, I have w3 total cache plugin with enabled "page cache" and "fragment cache" option. But I can't implement fragment caching on my website! 
Look:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
    echo date('d m Y H:i');
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

This ^ code is working perfectly. But when I want to use some wordpress functions like in this code:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
    echo get_the_ID(); echo get_query_var('category');
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

its ^ working only for first page load. After reloading it ain't showing anything. What am I doing wrong?
p.s. late initialization is enabled

Answer (score 1):

INSTEAD OF:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
    echo get_the_ID();
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

USE:

```
 <!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
        echo '<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>';
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm trying it like this, but I'm not sure it works or not correctly.

```
<!-- mfunc <?=W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY?> -->
  <?php echo $something_else; ?>
<!-- /mfunc <?=W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY?> -->
```